# Vagrant with Chef - Errors when provisioning VM

Tags: ruby, postgresql, chef-infra, vagrant

I'm having a difficult time getting a VM set up with Vagrant.

Whenever I use vagrant>provision, Chef fails:

[2014-03-15T19:16:08+00:00] ERROR: chef_gem[pg] (postgresql::ruby line 39) had an error: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
> /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for pg_config... yes
> Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
> checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes 
> checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
> checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no 
> checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no 
> Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
> the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
> options.
```

I'm struggling to understand what to do here. I have manually installed postgres on the VM, removed postgres from the cheffile but still Chef fails.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the [`postgresql::ruby`](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/postgresql#ruby) recipe to install the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the postgres client libraries on the VM for the pg gem